should we delete move constructor and assignment in this code?
in this code On_heap is a wrapper that manages an object on heap. Are deleting move constructor and assignment here mandatory?
template<typename T>
struct On_heap {
On_heap() :p(new T) { } // allocate
˜On_heap() { delete p; } // deallocate
T& operator∗() { return ∗p; }
T∗ operator−>() { return p; }
On_heap(const On_heap&) = delete; // prevent copying
On_heap operator=(const On_heap&) = delete;
private:
T∗ p; // pointer to object on the free store
};


If your move ctor / operator correctly set p to nullptr then I don't see a reason to remove them.

First of all you are deleting the copy constructor and assignment here (explicitly) and not move constructor. A default move constructor will not be generated as you have explicit declaration of copy constructor.  I think it makes sense to delete the copy and assignment as you want to manage memory through your class.

You seem to be reinventing std::unique_ptr. Which is in fact movable. To the extent you want to write your own class in the first place, you likely want to make it movable as well.


Are deleting move constructor and assignment here mandatory?

No, C++ does not mandate you delete the move constructor or move assignment here.
Neither does the law of any civilized nation.
There may be coding standards that employers provide that mandate deleting the move constructor or move assignment, but I leave that to you and your employer.

As to questions you did not ask, what happens when you fail to delete those two special member functions?
Well, as you have implemented or deleted another special member function, the automatic version will not be generated.  Most attempted use of them will then find the deleted special member function and generate an error.
It won't let you move the object.
Now, as you appear to be reimplementing unique_ptr, experience has shown that you want to allow movement.  Smart pointers that don't allow movement, like QScopedPtr, are usually considered overly restrictive.  Often you want to create a resource in one bit of code, and then store it somewhere else; and scoped non-movable pointers get in the way of this.
So you probably should have move operations; these should null the pointer it owns, and the cleanup code should not-crash when given a null resource.
So in this sense, if you want to permit the object to be moved, then it is indeed mandatory that you implement move constructor and move assign.
Mandatory depends on who and what is doing the mandating.

if you develop a library with such an object without deleting move const/assingment or handling them correctly then it will lead to a bug in the application that uses this library and tries to move this object. whose is the responsibility to make sure that either those functionalities are correctly implemented or to prevent using them?

@MBagher "it will lead to a bug" - what bug are you talking about?  Please demonstrate with a concrete case.  I do not know what the "a bug" you are referring to is exactly, and short of a concrete case I doubt I will.
